# What is wrong this following code?

Tags: java, user-interface, joptionpane

I wanted to add an ImageIcon to the JOptionPane when displayed but when i run the JOptionPane shows up but the icon does not ...

note : the argument "this" is the Frame and santorini is a game I made and the JOptionPane is supposed to be displayed when game is over to announce the winner ... so any help ?

```
if (santorini.isGameOver()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
        this, 
        "Winner is " + santorini.getWinner().getName(), 
        "Winner is",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
        new ImageIcon ("pyramid2nlayer 1.png")
    );
}
```

Comment: For starters, it's indented like Kwazimodo.

Comment: Have you got the answer? Let us know and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me. For this example path is same as java file.

```
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image hello.jpg"));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "hi", "hello", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way..

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(TestOptionPane04.class.getResource(path for image file));

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Hello world","Hello", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
```

Comment: Java doesn't recognize TestOptionPane04

Comment: Sorry for that.. Here TestOptionPane04 is the class . You can directly use getClass().getResources(path) .